# Change all screens orientation at run time in android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, screen-orientation

Use Case: I am developing android application in Tablet and Android TV, Which contains "Rotate screen" option in every screen. My Query is if user hit the rotate the screen option i want to change screen orientation throughout the application. i.e. all screen should change their default setting to that opted screen orientation.

Answer (score 2):

```
 Hold the flag to change the orientation and verify it at onCreate(); and change it. 



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if(isLandScape)
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
else
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);    
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can give you one way for your need :

1. Add `android:configChanges = "orientation"` against your activities
2. Step 1 will enable your activities to get a callback `onConfigurationChanged(Configuration new)` from Android system when `Rotation` button is clicked by user
3. `Override` `onConfigurationChanged()` callback in your activities
4. You'll get new config object as parameter inside `onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)`. Store it centrally, so that all applications can access it.
5. Write code in all of your activities to first check centrally stored `configuration` value, if it is null (as initially), you can start in `default` as either Portrait or Landscape according to your app's need

   ```
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       // Make getCurrentConfig() method available centrally via Interface or 
       Application level, depends on our logic
       if (getCurrentConfig() == LANDSCAPE) {
           setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
       } else if (getCurrentConfig() == PORTRAIT) {
           setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
       }
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

   @Override
   public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
       super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
       // Store newConfig centrally, this object describes current 
       configuration
       // For Example, if I have a singleton class which holds 
       configuration related things, I can do following
       // ConfigurationManager = Singleton class managing configuration 
       across app
       // getInstance() = method which will return singleton object of 
       ConfigurationManager
       // setConfiguration(Configuration config) = setter method will be 
       used to update configuration inside ConfigurationManager when 
       configuration changes happen
       ConfigurationManager.getInstance().setConfiguration(newConfig);
   }
   ```

This way, you can centrally manage current rotation changes across all activities
I hope this would help you

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Could you please share the code for onConfigurationChanged() method

Comment: @binaryakash I have added sample code of `onConfigurationChanged()` method, please check and if it helps, pls accept my answer

Answer (score 0):

On click of rotate screen option set a variable value. Check this variable in onCreate() method of every activity and set orientation as below: -

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        // Check the value of variable in if condition
        if (value.equals("landscape")) { 
           setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        }
       else {
          setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT); 
       }
   }
```

But make sure you do this for all the activities in your application. you might have to relaunch the application too tak effect.